# How can I make WPF instantiate a custom control in my view, using another custom control base class in my XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListView with 5 columns:

```
  <ListView x:Name="FieldList" ItemsSource="{Binding MonitorField}" SelectedItem="{Binding Field}" Margin="33,22,87,209" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Field Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Width="127" Text="{Binding Id}" Height="32" FontSize="16" IsReadOnly="False" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="File type" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Width="127" ItemsSource="{Binding ResourceTypeValues}"  SelectedItem="{Binding ResourceTypeToLoad}" Height="24" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Path" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <MyNamespace:PathControl Width="127" Text="{Binding ResourcePathToLoad, Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="32" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                    <MyNamespace:PathControl.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding BrowseFileCommand}" />
                                    </MyNamespace:PathControl.InputBindings>
                                </MyNamespace:PathControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>                
</GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Here is my custom control PathControl et TestControl that inherit from PathControl

```
public class PathControl : TextBox, IPathControl
{
    static PathControl()
    {
        //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PathControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PathControl)));
    }
}

public class TestControl : PathControl
{
    static TestControl()
    {

    }
}
```

What I would like to do is making WPF instantiate a custom control depending on my Combobox defining just before PathControl.

For example, if I select "Txt" in the combobox, I want to create a TxtControl that inherit from PathControl.

The mouse binding will call a different method depending on which custom control is instantiate.

Is it even possible ? Is there another way to implement this ?

Comment: Using MVVM, you have two models - `A` and `B`.  You design two views for them: `AView : BaseView` and `BView : VaseView`. You would create datatemplates in your resources like `<DataTemplate DataType-"{x:Type t:A}"><t:AView /></DataTemplate>`, etc. Content controls (such as a ListBox) bound to an instance of your model will automatically search out the correct DataTemplate to use in displaying it based on type.  And that's how MVVM works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define as resources the two datatemplates you want like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="case1">
 <c:PathControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

then the other

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="case2">
 <c:TestControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now create a DataTemplateSelector

```
public class SelectionTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
public DataTemplate Case1Template { get; set; }
public DataTemplate Case2Template { get; set; }

public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
DependencyObject container)
{

if( //Get the binding you need)
return Case1Template ;
else
return Case2Template ;
}
}
```

Now add another resource:

```
 <c:SelectionTemplateSelector 
    ImageTemplate="{StaticResource case1}" 
    StringTemplate="{StaticResource case2}" 
    x:Key="SelectionTemplateSelector " />
```

and finally instead adding a datatemplate add

```
ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SelectionTemplateSelector }"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I wasn't clear enough. The content of my ComboBox is dynamic and I would like classes which inherit from PathControl to be loaded from DLL. I want to have an application extensible by other programmers. Is it still possible ? maybe I should create another question. Thanks anyway